# How to find smallest positive real roots of $\left(At^2+Bt+C\right)\left(Dt^2+Gt+H\right)-k^2=0$ given $A,B,C,D,G,H\in C$ and $k\in R$?

Tags: complex-numbers, computational-mathematics, quartics

I am experimenting with quartics because of a computer program. I wanted to see if there is a simpler general way than using the quartic formula, or descartes, or ferrari methods to find the smallest positive real root of a quartic if I know that it is of the form:

$\left(at^2+bt+c\right)^2+\left(dt^2+gt+h\right)^2-k^2=0$ where $t\in R$ is what I am trying to solve for, and $a,b,c,d,g,h,k\in R$ are already defined constants.

Note: A computer needs to be able to compute this very fast so no algebraic manipulation except plugging variables into functions. This also means that newtons method is not the right tool because it wouldn't be a fast enough to guess where the starting value is such that it converges to the correct root without becoming unstable.

Anyways, I decided to try the $a^2+b^2=\left(a+bi\right)\left(a-bi\right)$ equation on the $\left(at^2+bt+c\right)^2+\left(dt^2+gt+h\right)^2$ part of the equation and I got
$\left(\left(a+di\right)t^2+\left(b+gi\right)t+\left(c+hi\right)\right)\left(\left(a-di\right)t^2+\left(b-gi\right)t+\left(c-hi\right)\right)-k^2=0$.

So let $A=a+di$, $B=b+gi$, $C=c+hi$, $D=a-di$, $G=b-gi$, and $H=c-hi$

This is how I got to the equation with the six complex coefficients from the question title. I also noticed that half of them are conjugates of the other half which is expected.

If equation didn't have this $-k^2$ term, this would be easy because I could just solve both complex quadratics for zero using the quadratic formula, but the $-k^2$ term is creating a dead end in this experiment. I am not sure how the roots of a quartic change when subtracting a constant term.

Is there a way that I can solve this  with the $-k^2$ term? Or is there a proof that this cannot be solved with the $-k^2$ term, without using any of the methods I have rejected in this post?

Comment: Have you tried the [Quartic Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation)? It may look intimidating at first but I'm sure you can find implementations of it online.

Comment: I listed it as something I didn't want to use unless the method I am experimenting with is impossible in the first paragraph. Mostly, I didn't really want to use it because I only need the smallest positive real root.

Comment: Also please keep in mind I am trying to minimize the amount of operations needed for a result.

Comment: @PlatinumFrog 1/ It is unnecessarily confusing that you use the same notations for the complex coefficients in the title, and the real coefficients in the body of the question. 2/ The equation is not guaranteed to have any real roots, let alone positive real roots, in general. If there are additional known constraints on the coefficients which do guarantee positive real roots, then you should spell out in the question what those constraints are.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion of the notation, and yes I know there is no guarantee for positive real roots, but I was going to see if I could use this method to find all the roots and compare them or find some discriminant that I can use to figure out if there are real roots or not.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to find an implementation that works, then work on improving the number of operations used only if it turns out to be necessary for your application. Computers are much faster than most people realize.